# Научите как правильно работать с mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Наличие баз данных и таблиц , приведенных в коде:
    DATABASE - database  ,
    TABLES   - users

```
 <?php
 echo 'Проверка работоспособности проекта!';

 $db = mysqli_connect( "127.0.0.1", "root", "root");
 mysqli::select_db("database", $db);

 $result = mysqli::query("SELECT * FROM `users` ");
 var_dump($result);
```

В браузере проект показывает белый экран (хотя проверочное эхо само по себе работает)...

Comment: Код надо не выдумывать самому, а брать из примеров в документации.

Comment: я посмотрел использование mysqli в учебнике пхп

Comment: @Александр из учебника тоже надо не фантазировать, а копировать в точности. Программирование - не литература, изложение своими словами здесь не работает.

Comment: @Александр, [посмотрите документацию](http://www.php.su/articles/?cat=phpdb&page=010), там есть прекрасные примеры с проверками соединения на каждом этапе. Так же выполните простой запрос, что бы проверить, что соединение работает без привязки к чему-либо `select 1+1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так.

```
// полезные настройки PHP
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow');

// задаем параметры подключения
$db_hostname = 'localhost';
$db_database = 'database';
$db_username = 'root';
$db_password = 'root';

// устанавливаем режим выброса исключений при ошибках
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

// создаем соединение
$connection = new mysqli($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database);
mysqli_set_charset($connection, "utf8");

// выполняем запрос
$result = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM users");
$myrow = $result->fetch_assoc();
echo $myrow['ИМЯ СТОЛБЦА'];
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53508/discussion-on-answer-by-n-osennij------mysqli).